# JavaFX CSS for nested SplitPanes

Tags: css, javafx

I'm tasked with styling/skinning a JavaFX application. I'm trying to do as much in CSS stylesheets as possible rather than in the code. I've got a question about nested SplitPanes: when the application is rendered, is there anything that is created surrounding the inner SplitPane that gets in between the outer SplitPane and the inner SplitPane in the parent/child hierarchy of nodes.

Here's a little test application that mimics my full application:

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
root.setId("root");
Label mws_header = new Label("This is the header");
root.setTop(mws_header);
Label sidebar = new Label("This is the sidebar");
root.setLeft(sidebar);

SplitPane outer = new SplitPane();
outer.setId("mws_pano_360_split");
outer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
root.setCenter(outer);
Label bigGraphic = new Label("This is the top");
outer.getItems().add(bigGraphic);

SplitPane inner = new SplitPane();
inner.setId("flat_data_split");
inner.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
Label label1 = new Label("This is the left");
Label label2 = new Label("This is the right");
inner.getItems().addAll(label1, label2);

outer.getItems().add(inner);
```

In the CSS, what I'd like to do is get to the inner SplitPane using direct child syntax:

```
BorderPane > SplitPane > SplitPane {
    /* all kinds of styling of background colors */
}
```

But instead, what I have to do is treat it as a descendant:

```
BorderPane > SplitPane SplitPane {
    /* all kinds of styling of background colors */
}
```

So what might be getting in between the outer SplitPane and the inner SplitPane? I'd love to have a tool that lets you inspect the parent/child nodes in the hierarchy but so far haven't found one.

Comment: The `SplitPane` probably has some kind of container that manages its content. *"I'd love to have a tool..."* [This one](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/)? It's probably worth considering, though, since the underlying structure of the `SplitPane` is not documented, that you might not want to rely on the exact structure. Probably treating it as a direct descendent is going to be more robust to, e.g. the user upgrading their JDK version.

Comment: Consider to use the IDs (mws_pano_360_split, flat_data_split) or some style classes.

Comment: Using either ids or style classes doesn't solve the problem - you still have to get to the inner pane by descendant instead of child. I just used the element in my example just to be more obvious.

Comment: If you only have one level of nested split panes you can try SplitPane > * > SplitPane.

Comment: Surely just `#flat_data_split { /* all kinds of styling... */ }` would select the inner split pane (without any need for accessing it through its ancestor/parent nodes)? But play with [scenic view](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) if you really want to see how it's put together.

Comment: Thanks for the link to scenic view - it works great. I put ids into the example code just to test whether ids would work. I was actually happy that they didn't, because the way this application is coded there aren't any ids (graphic objects are contained in a separate json file and are not created with ids that can be used.) My job in skinning the app needs to somehow be able to address the objects via the hierarchy, so I just have to figure out the best way to address things. I think you're correct that the most robust way is to address things as descendants rather than the exact structure.

Comment: *"So what might be getting in between the outer `SplitPane` and the inner `SplitPane`?"* It's determined by the skin. The default skin currently uses a inner class extending `StackPane` to contain the individual items...

Comment: The id approach should work: if it doesn't something else is likely wrong.

Comment: Clarification - yes, the #nodeid approach works, if you want to address it directly to that node. But what I meant was that trying "#root > #mws_pano_360_split > #flat_data_split" in the CSS does not work. "#root > #mws_pano_360_split #flat_data_split" does work.